# OkHttp leaked connection to googleads.g.doubleclick.net

Tags: android, admob, okhttp

I'm getting the following warning in Logcat:

> OkHttpClient: A connection to https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?

And I do use OkHttp in my app, but I don't use it to connect to this URL. Is this a warning for something Google Ads/AdMob is doing? Are Google Ads/AdMob using OkHttp too? Should I worry about this warning?

Answer (score 0):

It’s probably a leak by your AdMob code. You should report the warning to the authors of that code.